# how can I copy all my music from my PS3 to my PC wirelessly

Tags: file-transfer, ps3

I am currently trying to copy all my music from PS3 to my PC however I can't seem to achieve what I need to.

I can connect to my PC as  media server but that seems more Pull than Push (unless I am missing something)

Is there any way I can say to my PS3 copy my music to this PC??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling, it doesn't look like it is possible to grab your music from your PS3 and move it wirelessly to your PC.  However, according to a post in [this forum thread](http://www.gamespot.com/pages/forums/show_msgs.php?topic_id=26173480), it is possible to use either a flash drive or an ethernet cable to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have modified (hacked) your PS3, you can hook it up via ethernet and run `blackbox`.

This serves as a connection between the PS3 and PC using a special IP and DNS. Blackbox serves as an FTP client in this case.